# A better verb for "cement" in "cement one's interest"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

Is there a better word for *cemented* in the following sentence?

> All the experiences I went through have **cemented** my interest in this field.

I was told "cemented" doesn't quite fit in and I was asked to find a replacement. Any synonyms, anyone?

I know this question sounds vague, please comment if you need additional details.

Comment: reinforced? *reinforce:* strengthen (an existing feeling, idea, or habit).

Comment: hmm.. it is not an existing idea though. How do I put it.. it's more like' established'. Any word that's more appropriate than established/cemented?

Comment: It's not very imaginative but *solidified* is fairly idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

The noun *cement* refers to the binder in concrete which in combination with water forms a paste which solidifies into mortar, which is solid and strong. Together with sand and stone this forms concrete.

In the context of *All the experiences I went through have cemented my interest in this field.*, cementing means strengthening or solidifying.

I would say the most suitable alternative word word be *solidified* here:

**All the experiences I went through have solidified my interest in this field.**

Answer (score 1):

I would say confirmed. In this context.

Comment: "Cemented" is it took your interest and made it stronger, tenfold. "Confirmed" is it took your interest and went "yeah well I guess it's, like, okay..."

Comment: Well I think you "confirm" your interest in something by doing it a few times. So all these experiences confirmed that he likes what he's been doing, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

To me,HARDENED or SET can also be used in the place of CEMENTED in the sentence.
AZEEZ TANUR

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say [ingrained](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ingrained), meaning deeply embedded

Answer (score 0):

I think 'cemented' is perfect. I'd change 'All the experiences I went through ... ', though, to 'My experiences have cemented my interest in this field'.

Answer (score -2):

I guess *cemented* or its synonym won't fit the context that you have mentioned. Try *strengthened*, *steeled*, etc.

Comment: petrified? at what?

Comment: at my interest in the field

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&hl=en&q=define+petrified

Comment: @NiteshVerma Doesn't _pertrified_  mean startled? or 'scared out of your wits'

Comment: Yes, but it also means turned to stone. [petrify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/petrify?q=petrify)

Comment: yes the intent is just to stone down the interest in the field as per the context mentioned